# Does netmask and option subnet-mask have to be equal on a dhcpd.conf definition?

Tags: networking, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

Using linux servers on a *dhcpd.conf* file I can make a definition of ip ranges that the server will assign to host computers on the internal net:

```py
subnet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.0.0.20 10.0.0.100;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

*Should subnet-mask and netmask be the same?*

I understand that subnet-mask has to be more restrictive or at least the same that the netmask provided.

*¿Which effect has netmask on the subnet defined?*

Comment: Surely the `option subnet-mask` line is redundant if it's only setting it to the same as the earlier declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not always.
The parameters that start with the keyword option are referred to as options. These options control DHCP options; whereas, parameters configure values that are not optional or control how the DHCP server behaves.

```
subnet 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.252 {
   range 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2;
   option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
}
```

the above code will give your clients, an ip address start from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.2 but the subnet mask on your clients will be 255.255.255.0

Comment: So if both definitions are valid ones I need to be carefull to make masks coherent so i don't put ips out of scope

Comment: yes becarefull with that. if you find out my answer was helpful you can accept my answer as correct answer and give me a vote up so both of us will get reputation. thaks

Comment: I'll do, i'm just waiting a 2nd answer wich would be complementary. My votes are not allowed yet because of rep but you'll see the vote when I reach.